# to remove location of grass

Tags: grass-gis

i wan to delete the Location of a data set in grass gis 6.4.4 using grass command. For customizing grass for our data set, i need to load different location and mapsets of different regions of country.I seen for mapset removal. To remove location is there any command?

Comment: If you work in Linux or Mac OS X, you can use all the Bash commands (or other Shell) from the Grass shell.

Answer (score 3):

There is a related button in the startup screen (lower right): http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/File:Wxgui-startup-gnulinux.png which allows you to delete a location. Or simply delete the location directory like any other directory on your computer.