# How to remove a map in QGIS GRASS Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-grass-plugin

In QGIS Desktop 2.18.14 with GRASS 7.2.2, I started cleaning vector layers and it worked nicely.

Issue: every time I load a shapefile onto GRASS Plugin by `v.in.ogr` (`v.in.ogr.qgis`), it creates a map (its own vector set) within GRASS Database.

How can I remove these maps? Most of them are just temporally files and I do not want them to stay in the harddisk forever.

In earlier documentation there appears a module(?) "GRASS Browser" which could be used to delete maps, or probably `g.remove` in GRASS (standalone) is the function I need, but I cannot locate them.

**EDIT** I might have begun with a wrong assumption that we needed to clean mapsets / maps levels. GRASS users can simply [remove *Location* by deleting the folder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/130708/84455) and start over. It seems fairly practical way to deal with pile of maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the tool is listed in the toolset. But you should still be able to access the `g.remove` module from the **GRASS shell** and use the command prompt with something like:

```
g.remove type=vector name='myVectorMap'
```

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, then I will have to remember name of maps I made...

Comment: @Kazuhito - Most welcome! You could just load up the standalone and use the GUI instead ;)

Comment: Found wildcard [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179462/using-wild-cards-in-grass-to-remove-files). Sorry for my comment above, and thanks again!

Comment: @Kazuhito - That's a good solution, nice find :)

Comment: Yes, thank you Joseph. Just a quick test, but `g.remove -f type=vector pattern="*"` seems to sweep clean!